# Making of web based email service just like yahoomail,gmail

Tags: php

how to make a webbased email service such as inbox, outbox, deletemail, reply ,forward mail etc.

Is it possible to make with PHP. just give some guidelines from where to start.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Rockers. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 9):

I don't mean to sound flippant, but you couldn't pick a bigger wheel to reinvent or one more pointless. If you must make your own, look on Google for one of the very many open source web projects that are out there to use as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. You will need a SMTP and a POP/IMap servers. There are a ton of e-mail clients already written in php.

Here is a tutorial.
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Building-A-PHPBased-Mail-Client-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

this one is my favorit
https://sourceforge.net/projects/myphpim/